Perforce after update no longer will run
After doing an update to Perforce it will no longer run. I have fixed a few things, like adding the P4PORT env variable to the master.conf file. This wasn't needed before. I also manually rebuilt the DB from the latest journal file. Also, if I run p4d in the command line it runs fine with an empty db.
These are the current errors I get:
× helix-p4dctl.service - LSB: Starts all Perforce services
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/helix-p4dctl; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-05-30 09:45:30 EDT; 1h 49min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 7496 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/helix-p4dctl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 39ms

May 30 09:45:28 myserver p4dctl[7505]: error:         Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
                                                          connect: 127.0.0.1:1666: Connection refused
May 30 09:45:28 myserver p4dctl[7507]: error:         Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
                                                          connect: 127.0.0.1:1666: Connection refused
May 30 09:45:28 myserver p4dctl[7508]: error:         Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
                                                          connect: 127.0.0.1:1666: Connection refused
May 30 09:45:29 myserver p4dctl[7509]: error:         Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
                                                          connect: 127.0.0.1:1666: Connection refused
May 30 09:45:30 myserver p4dctl[7501]: error:         'master' p4d: '/opt/perforce/sbin/p4d -p ssl:localhost:1666' exited with status 255.
May 30 09:45:30 myserver p4dctl[7501]: Started 0 services.
May 30 09:45:30 myserver p4dctl[7501]: error:         Not all services started successfully.
May 30 09:45:30 myserver systemd[1]: helix-p4dctl.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 30 09:45:30 myserver systemd[1]: helix-p4dctl.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 30 09:45:30 myserver systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Starts all Perforce services.

My config file:
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# p4dctl configuration file for Helix Core Server
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

p4d master
{
    Owner    =  perforce
    Execute  =  /opt/perforce/sbin/p4d
    Umask    =  077

    # Enabled by default. 
    Enabled  =  true

    Environment
    {
        P4PORT    =     ssl:localhost:1666
        P4ROOT    =     /opt/perforce/servers/master/root
        P4USER    =     super
        P4SSLDIR  =     ssl
        PATH      =     /bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/perforce/bin:/opt/perforce/sbin

        # Enables nightly checkpoint routine
        # This should *not* be considered a complete backup solution
        MAINTENANCE =   true
    }
}


Look in the log file of the P4D instance (you may want to set P4LOG to log to a file; it defaults to stderr) for the error that's emitted on startup.  Server startup errors are almost always one of the following:

you need to run p4d -xu to migrate the database (the fix: do it)
your license is expired so you're ineligible for upgrades (the fix: either downgrade or renew your license)


I added P4LOG = /var/log/perforce/p4err to my master.conf file and there was no output to the file.

Maybe a permission problem on that path?  I'd try just running p4d -r /opt/perforce/servers/master/root -p ssl:localhost:1666 -L stderr to just see what error you're getting on startup, and then debug the log issue after your server is up and running.

So the fix was changing permissions on the SSL dir and the two files within it. I found this in the logs/log file. Thanks, you got me looking in the right direction.
The only problem now is that I used to be able to do all the super commands as myself, now I must actually login to the server as super.

That should be as simple as either a chown (if you're talking about local filesystem permissions) or granting yourself more permissions via p4 protect (if you're talking about permissions within Perforce).

There are only two users plus super. My username was never in the DB, but I was always able to do whatever I wanted with my username, this seems to have changed in the last update.

That means that you had no protection table defined.  My guess is that it wasn't the update per se, but a side effect of whatever you did to install the update (i.e. you or some tool you used ran p4 protect for the first time as the super user).  Again, easy fix: run p4 protect and change super user super * //... to super user * * //....
